# How to lift homotheties of a direct summand $P$ to become homotheties over the direct-sum $P\bigoplus Q$?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

Let $R$ be a commutative ring,  $M$ be a left $R$-module and $a\in R$.  Then the scalar multiplication $f(m)=am$  is an $R$-module endomorphism called homothety.  Suppose that $M=M_1\bigoplus M_2$ and $g:M_1\to M_1,m_1\mapsto rm_1$ is any homothety of $M_1$.  Can $g$ be lifted to become a homothety of $M$.  In other words, is there any endomorphism $h:M\to M$ such that $\bar{g}=g\circ h$ or $\bar{g}=h\circ g$ is a homothety of $M$, so that in this case we have $\bar{g}(m)=tm,$ for some $t\in R$ and for all $m\in M$?

I have been trying this in the following way:  Define a projection $e:M\to M_1$ such that $\bar{g}=g\circ e$ is an endomorphism of $M$.  Then for any $m=(m_1,m_2)\in M, \bar{g}(m)=g\circ e(m_1,m_2)=g(m_1)=rm_1$.  However, this is not right since $rm_1\neq rm$, so it is not the scalar endomorphism.  Is there a counter example to this problem?

Comment: why can you just take the map $M\to M$ via $m\mapsto rm$? this is a homothety by definition, and its restriction to $M_1\leqslant M$ will be $g$

Comment: (however, perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question; it's not quite clear what you mean by the composition $g\circ h$, since the domain of $g$ is $M_1$ and the range of $h$ is $M$, so it doesn't make sense in general to compose these two maps)

Comment: typo, meant to say "why *can't*" in my first comment

Comment: The composition of $g\circ h$ was just an idea like in the case with $g\circ e_1$ where $e_1^2=e_1\in \text{End}_R(M),$ is a projection to $M_1$ and $g\in \text{End}_R(M_1)$.

Comment: I see, so is you question "can $g$ be lifted to become a homothety of $M$"? in that case, why can't you just take the map $M\to M$ that sends $m$ to $rm$? this is a homthety, and its restriction to $M_1\leqslant M$ will be $g$

Comment: Thank you!  However, how do I guarantee that every homothety in $M_1$ must coincides with some homothety of $M$ restricted to $M_1$?   In other words, aren't there any other homotheties of $M_1$ that do not correspond to any restricted homotheties of $M$?

Comment: ah! well, unless I've misunderstood, in your question you say that a homothety of $M_1$ is by definition a map $M_1\to M_1$ of the form $m\mapsto rm$ for some fixed $r\in R$, right?

Comment: The homothety of $M_1$ is a map $M_1\to M_1$ of the form $m_1\mapsto rm_1$ for all $m_1\in M_1$ and for some $r\in R$.

Comment: indeed! so, won't then just taking the homothety $M\to M$ given by $m\mapsto rm$ restrict to $g$ on $M_1$?

Comment: Okay, Thank you I have got it!

Comment: my pleasure, happy it helped! :) if it's okay with you, I will post this as an answer

Comment: Yes, it makes a lot of sense for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this off the unanswered queue: fix $r\in R$ and let $g:M_1\to M_1$ be the homothety given $m_1\mapsto rm_1$. Then the map $f:M\to M$ defined by $m\mapsto rm$ is also a homothety, and it restricts to $g$ on the submodule $M_1\leqslant M$, as desired.